# Using both Local Database and Cloud Database at the same time in Mobile Development

Tags: database, flutter, mobile-development

I am Developing a mobile application using Flutter.I am currently using only Cloud Database with Firebase.My app is basically tracks user's daily workouts.So as i said before i am only using Cloud Database and fetching data from cloud all the time is slowing my app.I just learned there is a hybrid database approach which you can store all the datas in Cloud and also in device in Local database.I am thinking of authenticating the user with Firebase and then i will fetch the workout datas from Local Database which stored in the device.I don't want user's datas would gone when user delete the app and the local database so i will synchronize the data in local database and cloud database every night.What i wonder is should i use this approach? is it a good idea? if it's not a good idea what are your advices for make my app faster?

Thank you for your answers.

I tried nothing yet.I will rewrite my app based on your answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My question is more technical than practical so i don't have a code for the question yet.